# Trigger to update multiple tables

Tags: sql-server

trying to create a trigger which should insert data into three tables upon insertion of its parent table.

`Diagram`

[image]

`Table_1`

[image]

`Table_2`

[image]

`Table_3`

[image]

`Table_4`

[image]

And my object explorer

[image]

The code block I'm trying to use is

```
USE [demo1]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[autoupdate]
    ON [dbo].[Table_1]
    AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO dbo.Table_2(ONEID) 
        SELECT ONEID FROM INSERTED i
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Table_2 t2 WHERE t2.ONEID = i.ONEID) 
        AND i.ONEID IS NOT NULL;

END

GO
```

It works and updates the `Table_2` with the data taken from `ONEID`. Now How can I modify this to insert `ONEID` to rest of the tables?

`For Dave`

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Table_2(ONEID)
SELECT ONEID FROM INSERTED i 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Table_2 t2 WHERE t2.ONEID = i.ONEID) 
AND i.ONEID IS NOT NULL;

INSERT INTO dbo.Table_3(ONEID)
SELECT ONEID FROM INSERTED i 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Table_2 t2 WHERE t2.ONEID = i.ONEID)
AND i.ONEID IS NOT NULL;

INSERT INTO dbo.Table_4(ONEID)
SELECT ONEID FROM INSERTED i 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Table_2 t2 WHERE t2.ONEID = i.ONEID) 
AND i.ONEID IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Wouldn't it just be take your trigger's insert and copy and paste it two times, change the references to Table_2 to Table_3 and Table_4?

Comment: @Dave.Gugg Check the updated question... Is that what you meant?

Comment: Yes, but what about inside the sub-selects?

Comment: @Dave.Gugg Umm not sure I understand what you are saying..

Comment: @Dave.Gugg please post your answer and explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Table_2(ONEID)
SELECT ONEID FROM INSERTED i 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Table_2 t2 WHERE t2.ONEID = i.ONEID) 
AND i.ONEID IS NOT NULL;

INSERT INTO dbo.Table_3(ONEID)
SELECT ONEID FROM INSERTED i 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Table_3 t3 WHERE t3.ONEID = i.ONEID)
AND i.ONEID IS NOT NULL;

INSERT INTO dbo.Table_4(ONEID)
SELECT ONEID FROM INSERTED i 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Table_4 t4 WHERE t4.ONEID = i.ONEID) 
AND i.ONEID IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: But wouldnt this take `ONEID` from `Table_2` to `Table_3` and from `Table_3` to `Table_4`? or am I misinterpreting your code?

Comment: Try running it and look at the execution plan - what does it do?